# Converting date column to day of month and month in a new column

Tags: r, time, strptime

I have this kind of data frame

```
 dat <- read.table(text = " count     date    
                              0    10/05/2012  
                              1    10/05/2013  
                              1    10/05/2014  
                                   ",header = TRUE)
```

I would like to have a new variable that will contain the following format:

```
> dat
  count       date DayMonth
1     0 10/05/2012    10-05
2     1 10/05/2013    10-05
3     1 10/05/2014    10-05
```

I tried some versions of strptime function like `dat$DayMonth<-strptime(dat$date, "%d/%m")`  but got strange resluts.
How can I get the desired result

Comment: I wonder, why the downvote? This is reasonable question with the right input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `as.Date` and `format`

```
dat$DayMonth <- format(as.Date(dat$date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d-%m")
dat$DayMonth
#[1] "10-05" "10-05" "10-05"
```

---

Using `strptime` converts to `POSIXlt/POSIXct` class, from which we can change to the format using `format`

NOTE: No external packages used

Answer (score 2):

Same solution using the packages `lubridate` or `anydate`.

```
library(lubridate)
dat$DayMonth <- format(dmy(dat$date), "%d-%m")

# dmy stands for day,month,year, can you use ymd etc. 

library(anytime)
dat$DayMonth <- format(anydate(dat$date), "%d-%m")
```